# Extracting pw_dir from posix::pwd::getpwnam_r

Tags: posix, rust, ffi

Trying to read an arbitrary user's home directory inside a Rust fn, and using the posix::pwd crate.

Unfortunately, I can't find any good example of that FFI use, and keep banging into various type errors on mutability of pointers and types.

My (non-compiling) example code is here:

```
let uname = "root";
let mut pwbuf = [0u8;4096];
let mut res : usize = 0;
let mut pwd = posix::pwd::passwd::new();
posix::pwd::getpwnam_r(uname.as_nt_str(), &mut pwd, &mut pwbuf, &mut res);
let hd = unsafe{ ffi::c_str_to_bytes(&pwd.pw_dir as &*const i8) };
if res == 0 {
    println!("root home dir is {}", hd);
} else {
    println!("getpwnam_r error {}", res);
}
```

Anyone got a bit of example code which can extract the homedir into a &str value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
extern crate posix;

use std::ffi;
use std::str;

use posix::AsNTStr;

fn main() {
    let uname = "root";

    let mut pwbuf = [0u8; 4096];
    let mut res: usize = 0;
    let mut pwd = posix::pwd::passwd::new();
    let rv = posix::pwd::getpwnam_r(&uname.as_bytes().as_nt_str(), &mut pwd, &mut pwbuf, &mut res);

    let p = pwd.pw_dir as *const _;
    let hd = unsafe{ ffi::c_str_to_bytes(&p) };
    let hd_str = str::from_utf8(hd).unwrap();
    if rv == 0 {
        println!("root home dir is {}", hd_str);
    } else {
        println!("getpwnam_r error {}", res);
    }
}
```

First, I've fixed several type-related errors. For example, `getpwnam_r` expects a reference to something which implements `NTStr` trait, so there is an `&` before `uname.as_bytes().as_nt_str()`. You also need to obtain `&[u8]` from `&str` before calling `as_nt_str()` because `AsNTStr` trait is implemented for `&[u8]` but not for `&str`. I've also extracted the cast to `*const i8` and added the conversion from `&[u8]` to `&str`.

Second, `res` argument is not the value you should check for errors. I'm not sure why the author of `posix` chose to represent it as `usize`, but `res` is in fact a pointer to the resulting `passwd` structure. You can find it in `man getpwnam_r` man page. You need to check the actual return value of `getpwnam_r` call in order to determine if any errors happened.

The above code prints the correct `/root` directory for me.

Comment: Thanks for this - the res usize thing was a brain fart from me. It compiles well now - although I'm getting the wrong user details for the inputs now (the details are valid, just not for the specified user; probably a system configuration/SELinux thing). But I understand the foreign pointer voodoo a little better now.

Comment: Actually, found the error. Looks like the AsNTStr is a bit unstable. If I replace `use posix::AsNTStr` with `use posix::ToNTStr`, and the `uname.as_bytes().as_nt_str()` by `uname.to_nt_str`, it returns correctly, repeatably.